# Limiting the number of logins by ip address in moodle

Tags: moodle

Am using Moodle for online quizzes locally in a lap environment.
I am facing a problem with students sharing log in credentials in the exam. so am searching for a solution that will associate every user with a single ip address for a period of time. is there is any way from moodle to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible to completely prevent without writing a new plugin to cache the login and restrict any new logins for a period of time. IP address probably isn't the best way to do this, as multiple students could be using the same IP address if sharing something like a WiFi connection at a campus or public location.

However, you can make it a little more difficult.

1.) Enable the "Limit concurrent logins" setting. You can find this in Site Administration > Plugins > Authentication > Manage Authentication.

2.) Try [this plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/quizaccess_onesession). It will cache login information for a student when accessing a quiz and prevent another computer from logging in to the same account from continuing that same quiz.

3.) Use some sort of single-sign-on service which you can connect with Moodle via a SAML2 plugin [like this one](https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2). Look for a service that provides the specific functionality you're asking for.

4.) Use multi-factor authentication. You can combine this with option #3 above or look for a plugin supported by your current version of Moodle. [Lambda Solutions](http://www.lambdasolutions.net/services/moodle-plugins/) appears to have a commercial product for this. There is also an [older plugin on Moodle's site](https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_a2fa) that you could get a developer to update for you.